# Using Anchor Tags to Scroll to

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Currently I am using a simple `<a name>` to scroll; however, there is an issue with the top margins. There is too much space above them, and I'd like the titles to be flesh with the top. I lack javascript and jquery understanding and have researched tirelessly and nothing seems to work for me. Is there is simple solution for this, or a "best method / best practices" to pull this effect off?

```
    <h2><a style="color: #fff" name="classic">
<div class="menutitle">
<img src="/system/images/W1siZiIsIjIwMTMvMDUvMDEvMTNfMTdfMDNfMjA2X2NsYXNzaWNzLnBuZyJdXQ/classics.png" />
 </div>
</a>
    </h2>



 <div class="large-3 pull-9 columns" style="
position: fixed;
height: 50%;
width: 15%;
 ">

<div class="panel"> 
  <ul class="side-nav">
   <li><div id="appetizer2"><a href="#appetizer"><h3>appetizers</h3></a></div>
 </li>


    <li><div id="soupmenu"><a href="#soup"><h3>soups &amp; side salads</h3> </a>
  </div>
  </li>
    <li><div id="classic"><a href="#classic"><h3>classic</h3></a>
```

Comment: If there’s too much margin, why don’t you just eliminate that margin via CSS? (And btw., there’s no need to use `<a name="…">` any more – every element that has an `id` attribute set can be targeted via `<a href="#id">`)

Answer (score 0):

If you have an anchor tag like `<a href="#mydiv">Jump to My Div</a>` and a div like `<div id="mydiv">` then clicking on the anchor will jump down to the div, making the div at the top of the page - unless the div is near the bottom of the page, in which case the screen will not show the div at the top.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what your question is, if you could post a little code, as far as i understand you need to scroll the page you can use 
    a href="#someID" 
or javascript has the built in function scrollBy(xVal, yVal)